# How can you get the parent object reference of an object in java?

Tags: java, hashcode, super

I was trying to implement the hashCode method of and class which has a parent using Objects.hash() method.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super, attribute1);
}
```

I guess to create the hashCode I have to take into account the parent (the same way you have to check the parent while implementing equals).

It turns out the Objects.hash method is expected an object but super is a reserved word.

I know it can be implemented using others workarounds but, is there a way to call Objects.hash() method with a reference to the parent?

Comment: maybe `Objects.hash(super.hashCode())`

Comment: I guess this will inbox super.hashCode() into an Integer object and will use it a argument to the Objects.hash() method. It will work but the question remain unaswered. How can I get the reference of the parent object?

Comment: @DiegoRosado: There is no such thing as a "parent object". There is only the current object, pointed to by `this`. `super` just accesses `this`, with members looked up in a different way.

Comment: Thanks @newacct. I think I have a better picture now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "parent object". `this` is the current instance.
Not sure what you are trying to do here, but doubt that you need that either.

Just `attribute1.hashCode()` seems sufficient in your example. Or, if you have more than one attribute, then `Objects.hash(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, ...)`